# How to run more than one batch with vbs and set batch file path using environment variables?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have this script (courtesy of [@WesternSage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836834/rename-a-file-using-vbscript-launch-file-wait-and-rename-again)) that renames `foo.txt` to `foo.bat`, launches `foo.bat`, and when `foo.bat` ends, renames it back to `foo.txt`.

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Fso.MoveFile "foo.txt", "foo.bat"

SCRIPT = "foo.bat"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
Set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

objshell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & NewPath, 1, True

' Changes start here
'===================================================================

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

' Hold execution until cmd.exe process is done
Do 
    ' Get cmd.exe processes
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE 'cmd.exe'")
    WScript.Sleep 250
Loop While colProcessList.Count > 0

Fso.MoveFile "foo.bat", "foo.txt"
```

**The problem is:**

`foo.txt` (`foo.bat`) is in a path, which can change depending on the Windows version. For this I need to use environment variables to set the `foo.txt` path (example: `%homedrive%`), but this change doesn't work.

```
SCRIPT = "%homedrive%\test\foo.bat"
```

I need to call a second batch (`bar.bat`), when the first one ends (`foo.bat`). But this change does not work at the end of .vbs.

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Fso.MoveFile "%homedrive%\test\bar.txt", "%homedrive%\test\bar.bat"

SCRIPT = "%homedrive%\test\bar.bat"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

objshell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & NewPath, 1, True

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

' Hold execution until cmd.exe process is done
Do 
    ' Get cmd.exe processes
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE 'cmd.exe'")
    WScript.Sleep 250
Loop While colProcessList.Count > 0

Fso.MoveFile "%homedrive%\test\bar.bat", "%homedrive%\test\bar.txt"
```

Comment: You need to [return an environmental variable](https://ss64.com/vb/env.html).

Comment: Or [expand an environmental variable](https://ss64.com/vb/envexpand.html). You can search SO and find many examples of doing both.

Comment: @Squashman I am not an expert on vbs. If I knew how to do it I would not have asked the question. I have already read about it (https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_environment.php), but I do not know how to apply it. Could you be more specific and set an example in my case? Thank you

Comment: The `Run` method recognizes environment variables, but FileSystemObject methods do not, therefore you must expand the environment variable before using the variable with the script path.

Comment: If you read that page from Rob, then I would think you would have at least attempted, `homedrive = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEDRIVE%" )`.  You have so much more complicated Vbscript written in your code, the most simple thing to do in any language is to assign something to a variable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The question has two components. You have marked the first component as a duplicate. And the second? (will you also mark it as a duplicate?)

Comment: Why? You're not supposed to cram two questions into one in the first place. And it's not even clear to me what that second problem is. Please post a new question with a *lot* more information about what "but this change does not work at the end of .vbs" actually means.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The question is about applying environment variable to a path ... and also about launching 2 batch in sequence with a vbs script. The question is clear. But if you still want to follow marking as a duplicate, I guess you're the one in charge and nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

homedrive = objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEDRIVE%" )
Fso.MoveFile homedrive & "\test\bar.txt", homedrive & "\test\bar.bat"

SCRIPT = homedrive & "\test\bar.bat"
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

objshell.Run (script),1,True

Fso.MoveFile homedrive & "\test\bar.bat", homedrive & "\test\bar.txt"
```

Comment: Please review. The environment variable works. Maybe there is an error in its implementation (Not call .bat: SCRIPT = homedrive & "\test\foo.bat")

Comment: Now should works

Comment: A problem: I need .vbs to end (and close wscript.exe) when it launch the .bat. How do you do that?

Comment: The True value at the end of the line `objshell.Run (script),1,True` is what indicates that Run() should wait for the process to finish so don't need the WMI-based wait() function. The wscript process terminates when the batch file is finished, otherwise it could not rename the .bat to .txt

Comment: i got it. thanks a lot. pd: By the way. I have another similar question. I appreciate your time if you can read it. https://superuser.com/questions/1410033/autoend-vbs-when-it-runs-bat